# Can KeyAgreement be used without AlgorithmParameterSpec?

Tags: java, android, elliptic-curve, diffie-hellman, spongycastle

In my Android application working with **SpongyCastle**, I want to perform **ECDH Key Exchange** using a **specific elliptic curve** (*prime192v1*) and I am using this code to generate byte[] representation of private and public params:

```
        try{
            KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDH", "SC");

            org.spongycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("prime192v1");
            g.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());

            KeyPair kp1 = g.generateKeyPair();
            KeyPair kp2 = g.generateKeyPair();

            // Alice generated this
            byte[] privK1 = kp1.getPrivate().getEncoded();
            byte[] pubK1= kp1.getPrivate().getEncoded();

            // Bob generated this
            byte[] privK2 = kp2.getPrivate().getEncoded();
            byte[] pubK2= kp2.getPrivate().getEncoded();

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "Exception caught in ECDHInit function");
        }
```

now lets assume Alice and Bob save their private keys locally, exchange `pubK1` and `pubK2` and want to proceed with setting a shared secret (they have both keys now in `byte[]` format). I will describe only case of Alice, as for Bob this is identical:

```
KeyAgreement keyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH", "SC");

PrivateKey privateKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH", "SC").generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privK1));
PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH", "SC").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(pubK2));
```

**Here comes my question** - 
using the following code, I manage to get same shared secret for both Alice and Bob

```
keyAgreement.init(privateKey);
keyAgreement.doPhase(publicKey, true);

byte[] sharedSecret = SHA256(keyAgreement.generateSecret());
```

but I specify nowhere my special curve *prime192v1*

If I try to supply this in this way:

```
org.spongycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("prime192v1");

keyAgreement.init(privateKey, ecSpec);
keyAgreement.doPhase(publicKey, true);

byte[] sharedSecret = SHA256(keyAgreement.generateSecret());
```

an Exception is thrown saying

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: No algorithm parameters supported
```

Why can't I supply my desired parameter? Does the `KeyAgreement` somehow deduce this from the private key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out I had the answer right there in front of me in the Android Studio debugger. Upon inspecting `PrivateKey` object I found internal member `privateKey.ecSpec` which contains all the details of selected curve. So passing arguments is unnecessary and throws an error, **use the code without providing additional `ecSpec`**